# hyperref package with backref option - reference in abstract

Tags: bibtex, abstract, amsart, back-referencing

I'm using the `backref` option of the `hyperref` package, and `amsart` document class.
One of the reference is cited in the abstract. In the bibliography, this implies that the backref is written as "(document)".

Would it be possible to either :

- replace the "document" by "abstract"
- Or if not possible deactivate this `backref` reference, just for this `cite` ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        reference : \cite{foo} 
    \end{abstract}

    \maketitle 

    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

With the bibliography, `references.bib`

```
@article{foo,
    Author = {Author},
    Title = {Title}}
```

and the output :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}\makeatletter\phantomsection\def\@currentlabel{(abstract)}\makeatother
        reference : \cite{doody}
    \end{abstract}

    \maketitle

    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]